# NoClassDef Exception in Java using Jersey and Moxi

Tags: java, json, jersey, tomcat7

I'm new to Jersey, I got the app Up and running, However when I tried to use moxy for Json Processing I got stuck. I have overcome several problem. No after adding these two JARS:

- jersey-media-moxy-2.7
- jersey-entity-filtering-2.3

I get the following error:

```
    Apr 15, 2014 10:20:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet jersey-serlvet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/internal/ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider
    at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:610)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:800)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Your help is much appreciated. I'm not using maven or any other build or dependency tool.

Comment: Why are you using version 2.3 of this `jersey-entity-filtering-2.3` and 2.7 of `jersey-media-moxy-2.7`? The class your program can't find is in the jersey-media-moxy-2.7 jar. Check your classpath.

Comment: both are the latest! and It's in my classpath

Comment: no it's not. 2.7 is the most recent jersey-entity-filtering. See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-entity-filtering/2.7. Here's an argument to use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I used Json processing api jsonp. In my code I was processing on "low level" moxi does not support low level.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem using jersey, I just change the version to 
`<jersey.version>2.15</jersey.version>` and it works and I use this dependencies

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
           <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

and it works for me

Comment: This didn't worked for me, Still the same exception
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/internal/ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider`

Comment: Adding the jersey-entity-filtering for my version of jersey server worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had same problem, this worked for me.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
   <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

[Jersey REST API: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.EntityFilteringFeature.enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557831/jersey-rest-api-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-glassfish-jersey-message-filte/39558930?noredirect=1#comment66428826_39558930)

Answer (score 0):

Adding these dependency solved my problem.

```
*"org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.25.1",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:$versionJackson",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.8.9",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$versionJackson",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$versionJackson",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$versionJackson",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:$versionJackson",
"org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:2.15" *


versionJackson = "2.8.9"
```