# Jersey REST API: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.EntityFilteringFeature.enabled

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

in REST API using jersey, using Maven.
Maven successfully added mox and entity jars.

I'm getting below error when trying to get JSON type result.

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

content of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>in.alonebirddev.acs</groupId>
    <artifactId>messanger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messanger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messanger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

error :

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.EntityFilteringFeature.enabled(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Configuration;)Z
    at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:829)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 18, 2016 6:11:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /messanger threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.EntityFilteringFeature.enabled(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Configuration;)Z
    at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:829)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***and when removed version info from pom getting below error***

```
Sep 18, 2016 6:27:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/internal/ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider
    at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:829)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 18, 2016 6:27:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey Web Application
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/internal/ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider
    at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:829)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

!!! SOLVED.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the following

```
mvn dependency:tree


[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ messanger ---
[INFO] in.alonebirddev.acs:messanger:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.7:compile
```

I checked the repo for [this](http://(https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.10.x/ext/entity-filtering/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/filtering/EntityFilteringFeature.java)). The dependency you have is 2.7 and the method is not available in that revision. Have you tried adding a newer dependency to jersey-entity-filtering  and tried if it works ?

Comment: if I removed version for both dependencies , will it use latest jar files?

Comment: so what you suggest for above problem, shall I keep version info or not?

Comment: this is O/P, when I compiled without version, Caused by: it adding 2.23.2 jars `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
 ... 35 more`

Comment: Can you try adding the following dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.5.0